# Is it possible to have version tags on multiple branches in git?

Tags: git, version, git-tag

In brief, is it possible to have one branch of a repository and tag it say `1.0.0`, and then have (either before or after that tag) branched off with a tag `1.1.0` on the other branch?

How would composer react to this if I specified 1.1.0 and it was on a different branch beside master?

Also what happens if I merge the branch with 1.0.0 into the branch with 1.1.0?

Answer (score 0):

Tags don't work like branches in git. Think of a tag as labeling a specific commit so that you can easily refer to it later. Anywhere that you would specify a commit hash, you could use a tag name instead.

Git does not allow you to create any commits based off of a tag - that is what branches are for (in fact, if you checkout a tag, Git displays a warning that you can't create any new commits until you have checked out a branch first). If you want to make some changes based off of a tag, you'll need to create a branch first.

For example, if there is a tag called `1.0.0` that was created when that version was released, and since then `master` has additional commits for the next release, and you want to fix a bug in 1.0 you could do the following:

```
git checkout -b bug-fixes 1.0.0
...fix bugs...
git commit -a -m "fixed bugs in the release"
```

At this point, the `bug-fixes` branch is based off of the `1.0.0` tag (the first release of your program) and has the additional bug fixes in it.

Comment: Actually, tag names *do* work a lot like branch names in Git. The issue here is that branch names *also* only point to one specific commit; but branch names change *which* one specific commit over time, while tag names shouldn't, and users expect to look at multiple commits from a branch name. Also, when you check out a tag, you get into "detached HEAD" mode and *can* make new commits, which maybe Git shouldn't allow by default since people shoot themselves in the foot this way. :-) But the idea here in your answer is right; it's just all these messy details that are, well, kind of messy...

Comment: Yah, it was me.